# Show that the sequence $\{\int_{1}^{n} \frac{\cos t}{t^2} dt\}$ is Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Here is my attempt but I got stuck.

*Proof.* Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Choose $N$ (any hints for this) and let $m > n \geq N$. Then

\begin{align*}& \left|\int_{1}^{m} \frac{\cos t}{t^2} dt - \int_{1}^{n} \frac{\cos t}{t^2} dt\right|=\\ & = \left|-\int_{m}^{1} \frac{\cos t}{t^2} dt - \int_{1}^{n} \frac{\cos t}{t^2} dt\right| =\\&=\left|-\int_{m}^{n} \frac{\cos t}{t^2} dt\right| = \left|\int_{m}^{n} \frac{\cos t}{t^2} dt\right|=\\ &= \left|\frac{\cos(c)}{c^2}(n-m)\right| = \left|\frac{\cos(c)}{c^2}\right||n-m| =\\&= \frac{|\cos(c)|}{c^2}(m-n)\end{align*}
$\exists c \in (n,m)$ by Mean Value Theorem.

Any hints on how to proceed with this?

Comment: Think about upper bounds instead of exact evaluation. $|\int f| \leq \int |f|$.  And $|\cos(x)| \leq 1$ for all $x$.  Consider what the tails of $\int 1/t^2 \, dt$ look like.

Comment: How about $$
\left| {\int_m^n {\frac{{\cos t}}{{t^2 }}dt} } \right| \le \int_n^m {\frac{1}{{t^2 }}dt}  = \frac{1}{m} - \frac{1}{n}<\frac{1}{m}<\frac{1}{N}.
$$

Comment: Damn that's neat!

Answer (score 3):

If $m\geqslant n$, then\begin{align}\left|\int_0^m\frac{\cos t}{t^2}\,\mathrm dt-\int_0^n\frac{\cos t}{t^2}\,\mathrm dt\right|&=\left|\int_n^m\frac{\cos t}{t^2}\,\mathrm dt\right|\\&\leqslant\int_n^m\left|\frac{\cos t}{t^2}\right|\,\mathrm dt\\&\leqslant\int_n^m\frac1{t^2}\,\mathrm dt\\&=\frac1n-\frac1m\end{align}and, of course, if $m<n$, then $\left|\int_0^m\frac{\cos t}{t^2}\,\mathrm dt-\int_0^n\frac{\cos t}{t^2}\,\mathrm dt\right|\leqslant\frac1m-\frac1n$. So, if $\varepsilon>0$, just take $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $\frac1N<\varepsilon$. Then, if $m,n\in\Bbb N$ and $m,n\geqslant N$, then$$\left|\int_0^m\frac{\cos t}{t^2}\,\mathrm dt-\int_0^n\frac{\cos t}{t^2}\,\mathrm dt\right|\leqslant\left|\frac1n-\frac1m\right|<\frac1N<\varepsilon.$$

Comment: After step 4 $\big| \int_{n}^{m}\frac{\cos(t)}{t} dt \big|<\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m}<\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{m}<\epsilon$  whenever $n,m>N(\epsilon)>\epsilon/2$ Is it correct?

Comment: @ALMEra Yes. That is correct.

Comment: +1 your answer is very useful

Answer (score 1):

Good job with the first step of your attempt. Note that
$$\left|\int_m^n\frac{\cos t}{t^2}dt\right| \le \left|\int_m^n\frac{|\cos t|}{t^2}dt\right| \le \left|\int_m^n\frac{1}{t^2}dt\right| = \left|\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m}\right|$$